# How boto dyanmodb2 create table in region / understand create_table syntax?

Tags: boto

I'm trying to figure out how to create a table in a specific region using boto and dynamodb2. Previously I created a `Table` object which had a clear constructor, but does not appear to take a region parameter. Now I am trying to use `create_table` on the connection object, but the syntax is entirely different and not clearly documented.

So either, how do I use the `create_table` function or how can I specifiy a region for the `Table` constructor?

Answer (score 1):

The `Table` constructor also takes a `connection` parameter. The region of the `Connection` object is then used to construct the table.